# how to start workflow when list item got added in SharePoint hosted app list

Tags: workflow, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to start workflow when list item will be get added into my SharePoint hosted list using javascript?am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the workflow settings, there you'll find this option

[image]